# Paypal express, redirect text

Tags: paypal, express

So I have had a site setup and working for years for one of my websites.  I am replicating everything for another website.  I have everything up and running EXCEPT that on the Paypal thank you page before it redirects it says "Redirecting to Website A (My Name)" which is the business name of my account.

Is there a way to change what this says in the posted values?  So I could have it say "Redirecting to Website A" or "Redirecting to Website B" depending on which website I am coming from?  Or do I have to rename my business account to be something more generic?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the BRANDNAME parameter in your SetExpressCheckout request to set the business name (or whatever value) you want to show up where you explained.

Comment: Thanks Andrew.  However, https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/paypal-payments-standard/integration-guide/Appx_websitestandard_htmlvariables/ does not list "brandname" anywhere...does it translate as "brand_name" or is this not an option on the standard integration? I do see it on  "SetExpressCheckout API Operation (NVP)".

Comment: Ok, well, with Payments Standard you don't have that option.  You didn't say standard in your question title, though.  You said Express.

Comment: Sorry...I didn't know there was a difference.  It doesn't make sense that virtually everything else from Express would have a translation to Standard but this wouldn't be there.  I always thought Standard was one step above Express...but maybe not...

Comment: It's the other way around.  Standard is just basic HTML forms.  Actual API calls will give you much more freedom to customize things.